# Linq solution to get greatest numbers of arrays

Tags: c#, linq

Having an object that has as a `double[6]` array property as its geometric bounds:

```
 "xmin: " << bounds[0]  
 "xmax: " << bounds[1] 
 "ymin: " << bounds[2]  
 "ymax: " << bounds[3] 
 "zmin: " << bounds[4]  
 "zmax: " << bounds[5]
```

While iterating several objects and getting this property
I want to store the greatest value of xmax,ymax,zmax  of all iterated objects

What would be the best way to accomplish this task, I have this idea, however I would like to use Linq

```
    double[] max = new double[6];
    double xmax = 0.0;
    double ymax = 0.0;
    double zmax = 0.0;
    foreach (var o in myObject)
    {
        max = o.bounds;
        if (xmax < max[1])
        {
            xmax = max[1];
        }
        if (ymax < max[3])
        {
            ymax = max[3];
        }
        if (zmax < max[5])
        {
            zmax = max[5];
        }
   }
```

Comment: As @Selman22 already posted, you can use 3 `Max()` calls, but it will enumerator the source collection 3 times. You could use `Aggregate` to get desired results in just one enumeration, but it will definitely not be more readable than current `foreach`-based solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with this approach:

```
double xmax = myObject.Max(mo => mo.bounds[1]);
double ymax = myObject.Max(mo => mo.bounds[3]);
double zmax = myObject.Max(mo => mo.bounds[5]);
```

This produces very fast results.

If you want to iterate the enumerable only once using linq, then do it this way:

```
var max = myObject
    .Select(mo => mo.bounds)
    .Aggregate(
        new { x = double.MinValue, y = double.MinValue, z = double.MinValue },
        (a, b) => new
        {
            x = Math.Max(a.x, b[1]),
            y = Math.Max(a.y, b[3]),
            z = Math.Max(a.z, b[5]),
        });
```

While this is only one iteration my tests showed it was slower than the first method. The first method took 625ms and the second 705ms.

Comment: Have you tests simple `foreach` loop?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - I'll try now.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - Using `foreach` was fastest. If I used `Math.Max` I got 204ms. Using `?:` I got 350ms. It surprised me that `Math.Max` was quicker. I measure the garbage collections and there were zero gen0 collections on the "3xMax" and "foreach" methods. The "Aggregate" method consistently had around 202±2 gen0 collections.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using [`Enumerable.Max`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
double xmax = myObject.Select(x => x.bounds[1]).Max();
double ymax = myObject.Select(x => x.bounds[3]).Max();
double zmax = myObject.Select(x => x.bounds[5]).Max();
```

Note that this solution enumerates the collection three times unnecessarily.Your `foreach` loop is enumerates the collection only once, if I were you I would keep using the simple loop and use `LINQ` *only* when it's helpful.But ofcourse the decision is up to you.If your collection is not noticeably huge, you can prefer the more readable approach.

Comment: That would enumerate the collection 3 times, since `Max()` produces a scalar value.

Comment: yes, but OP wants to use LINQ.if you have a better solution using LINQ you are free to share.

Comment: I agree.  @gilly3, the downvote is if the post is not useful.  This clearly has use.

Comment: I don't see the point of using Linq if you aren't getting the benefit of deferred execution.  Iterate a collection 3 times just to save lines of code?  Concise code is nice, but not at the expense of performance.  There probably is a nice way to use Linq to get the values, but this isn't it.

Comment: @gilly3 Many times an increase in readability, and clarity is worth its weight in cycles. If the length of the list is not long (even 1000 elements is short), you would be looking at a performance difference of microseconds. And most applications do not need microsecond optimizations.

Comment: @gilly3 I can't disagree.but as I said I'm trying to provide an answer to the question, the question has the simplest solution already.

Comment: @gilly3 - I hear a lot of these concerns about performance issues. I reckon about 99 times out of 100 it doesn't make a scrap of practical difference. I just ran a test with 10,000,000 objects and even with iterating three times it produced the results in under half a second.  If the OP had that many points his performance issue wouldn't be calculating maximum values.

Comment: I realize I'm being nitpicky, and that this code may not be likely to lead to actual performance issues.  But, I'm interested in the principle.  How do you compute multiple aggregate values at once with Linq.

Comment: @gilly3 - Take a look at my answer. It works in one iteration, but is slightly slower due to the gen0 garbage collections.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Ah... I see we both posted similar answers.  It bothers me that the `.Aggregate()` approach is slower, but I can't argue with it.  [I see similar numbers](http://rextester.com/QNPL66232).  Good detective work identifying the gen0 garbage collector as the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ and iterate only one time, with the following code, but at the core you are doing about the same thing. Depending on what else your code needs to do, this may be better than your current approach.

Personally, I would lean towards Selman's example, for readability sake.

```
double[] max = new double[6];
double xmax = 0.0;
double ymax = 0.0;
double zmax = 0.0;
myLinqObject.ForEach(x => 
    {
        xmax = (x.bounds[1] > xmax ? x.bounds[1] : xmax);
        ymax = (x.bounds[3] > ymax ? x.bounds[3] : ymax);
        zmax = (x.bounds[5] > zmax ? x.bounds[5] : zmax);
    });
```

Important Note: Attempting this in code before C# 5.0 may result in wrong values because of a breaking change in the way linq closures worked. More info: http://davefancher.com/2012/11/03/c-5-0-breaking-changes/

Comment: This method turns out to be slower than using `Max` three times. My test showed for 10,000,000 objects that the "3xMax" method took 625ms, but this method took 1,025ms. This just goes to show that performance needs to be measured not imagined.

Comment: And the difference is 400ms per 10,000,000 objects. That goes to show that the performance is a waste of time to measure unless it is not performing fast enough for the expected use. @Selman22's answer (even if slower) is far more readable than the others, until performance in this part of code is inadequate

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Enumerable.Aggregate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549218(v=vs.100).aspx) with [`Math.Max()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x97k0y4(v=vs.110).aspx) to produce an array of max values:

```
myObject.Aggregate(new double[]{0,0,0}, (max, o) => new double[] {
    Math.Max(max[0], o.Bounds[1]),
    Math.Max(max[1], o.Bounds[3]),
    Math.Max(max[2], o.Bounds[5])
});
```

http://rextester.com/KSBAG65974

**Edit:** I would think this would be the correct approach, as it takes advantage of Linq's ability to iterate the collection just once to get all 3 values.  But, in practice, calling `Enumerable.Max()` 3 times is actually faster:  http://rextester.com/QNPL66232

+1 to [Enigmativity's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23530179/361684) for identifying that the cause of the slowness with `Aggregate()` is from garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
double max = myEnumerable.Max();
double min = myEnumerable.Min();
```